# How to Read UDP/TCP Header on Server

Tags: go, networking, tcp, udp

(For brevity, I'll just say UDP when I really need to do this for both UDP and TCP.)

For the purpose of writing a transparent tunneling application, I need to mess around with UDP headers.

From what I understand, there's no way I can read UDP headers with `net.DialUDP`/`net.ListenUDP`, so I must use the IP functions `net.DialIP`/`net.ListenIP`. However, I can't specify the port for the IP family of functions, and I got incredibly confused.

As an experiment I wrote a client

```
conn, err := net.DialIP("ip:udp", nil, &net.IPAddr{})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

packet := make([]byte, 12)
binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(packet, 42421)     // src port
binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(packet[2:], 42420) // dst port
binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(packet[4:], 12)    // length
copy(packet[8:], []byte("abcd"))              // payload
_, err = conn.Write(packet)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Which works as expected, sending `"abcd"` to `localhost:42420` from `localhost:42421`. For the client, apparently I just write the port in the header.

But I am stuck with the server

```
conn, err := net.ListenIP("ip:udp", &net.IPAddr{})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

buf := make([]byte, 1<<16)
for {
    n, _, err := conn.ReadFromIP(buf)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if len(n) < 8 {
        panic("invalid packet")
    }

    if binary.BigEndian.Uint16(buf[2:]) != 42420 {
        continue  // drop everything else?!
    }

    fmt.Println(buf[8:])
}
```

Doesn't this mean I read *all* packets sent my way, and have to drop all packets not addressed to `localhost:42420`?

What is the correct way to read UDP headers?

Comment: Why not use `net.ListenUDP`?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco How do I read UDP headers with that? I know I can reconstruct UDP headers, but doing so for TCP isn't that trivial.

Comment: Your code didn't seem to suggest that you're doing anything different with the header than the normal UDP listener would.  Also, isn't it a bad sign if you're indeed messing with the headers in such a way that the normal listeners can't handle them anymore? Doesn't that suggest that you should be using your own protocol, either on top of or replacing UDP/TCP?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Technically, ignoring the checksum is different than normal :) The problem is more with TCP, but an example for that is complicated and detracts from the problem. For a tunneling application, if I want to forward a TCP packet, I'm likely going to have to change the source port, and thus also the checksum. I'm not replacing TCP.